# How to Smooth Polygons after converting DEM using Raster to Polygon?

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, polygon, convert, spatial-analyst

I have a DEM SRTM that I classify using Spatial Analyst Tools > Reclass > Reclassify.

The result is box shaped so I go to Layer Properties > Display and choose cubic convolution. The result is smooth (not box shaped).

Next I convert to polygon using Conversion Tools > From Raster > Raster to Polygon choosing Simplify polygon. Then the polygon output is boxshaped.

So how do I create smooth polygons like from cubic display raster ?

Comment: [Smooth Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000013000000)?

Comment: What version and license level do you have access to?  Basic won't give you Smooth Polygon at 10.0

Comment: ET Geowizards (http://ian-ko.com/) have  a function for smoothing polygons, unfortunately not among the free ones though. However, unless you have too many features (100+ I think) it should still work.

Comment: I use ArcGIS 10.1. I don't know what license I have. I just want my polygon like cubic raster (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3GdWeowpDjDZXRvUXlFckNlS1U/edit?usp=sharing). I don't want my polygon like nearest neighbor (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3GdWeowpDjDaTNJclBNa1VhcUk/edit?usp=sharing). But, the polygon seems follow the neirest neighbor (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3GdWeowpDjDQ1dXZ1dGNG9oSXM/edit?usp=sharing). Well, my feature is more than 100, so I can't use ET Geowizards.